# one inner div seperates into 2 un-designated columns in mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a flexible-width div with a top margin of -99px, though I don't see where that's an issue. It's that div which, when viewed on mobile rather than desk-top, splits the text contents into 2 columns - and there are no columns whatsoever in my page! I want it display as the 3 centered lines vertically in one "column" within the box as it does in the screen version.

You can see it at http://myimagefiles.com/sally/prodbox.html. Code follows...

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cont {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid #000 3px;
}

.hdrrow {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 575px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.sec2 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#img1 {
  display: block;
}

#img2 {
  display: none;
}

.prodttl {
  width: max-content;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 11px solid #000;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -33px;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}


/*.prodttlsub { font-weight:bold; font-size:.95em; }*/

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .cont {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
  }
  .hdrrow {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 396px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .sec2 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  #img1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #img2 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .prodttl {
    max-width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: 8px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -99px;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: auto;
  }
  .smimg {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="hdrrow"><img id="img1" src="https://myimagefiles.com/bisbee/1000x575.png">
    <img id="img2" src="https://myimagefiles.com/bisbee/450x396.png"></div>
  <div class="prodttl"> PRODUCT<br>
    <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:.95em;">part jkls l fklj fo uwo uiwo 
        abcde <br>
        1234 5678910 111213</span> <br>
  </div>
  <div class="sec2">
    <p>[[Description]]</p>
    <div class="sat">
      <p style="color:#f00; font-weight: bold;">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p align="center"><img src="https://myimagefiles.com/bisbee/thanks.png"></p>
  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: flex;` should be `display: block;` in `.prodttl` for the small screen's CSS

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cont {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid #000 3px;
}

.hdrrow {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 575px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.sec2 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#img1 {
  display: block;
}

#img2 {
  display: none;
}

.prodttl {
  width: max-content;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 11px solid #000;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -33px;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}


/*.prodttlsub { font-weight:bold; font-size:.95em; }*/

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .cont {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
  }
  .hdrrow {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 396px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .sec2 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  #img1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #img2 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .prodttl {
    max-width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: 8px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -99px;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    height: auto;
  }
  .smimg {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="hdrrow"><img id="img1" src="https://myimagefiles.com/bisbee/1000x575.png">
    <img id="img2" src="https://myimagefiles.com/bisbee/450x396.png"></div>
  <div class="prodttl"> PRODUCT<br>
    <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:.95em;">part jkls l fklj fo uwo uiwo 
        abcde <br>
        1234 5678910 111213</span> <br>
  </div>
  <div class="sec2">
    <p>[[Description]]</p>
    <div class="sat">
      <p style="color:#f00; font-weight: bold;">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p align="center"><img src="https://myimagefiles.com/bisbee/thanks.png"></p>
  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The simple change of "flex" to "block" fixed it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The code need too be simplified, maybe do the mobile first and then add media queries for the bigger screen. To make it work **just comment or remove** `display: flex` from there:

```css
  .prodttl {
    max-width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: 8px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -99px;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    /* display: flex; */
    align-items: center;
    height: auto;
  }
```